Quaternions and isoclinic rotations
The complex numbers $ \mathbb{C} $ are a 2d real vector space. $ SO_2 $ acts on $ \mathbb{C} $ by rotations. There is a homomorphism $ SO_2 \to U_1 $ given by
$$
\phi \mapsto \phi(1) 
$$
The quaternions $ \mathbb{H} $ are a 4d real vector space. $ SO_4 $ acts on $ \mathbb{H} $ by rotations. There is a map $ R: SO_4 \to SU_2 $ (here $ SU_2 $ is thought of as the group of norm 1 quaternions) given by
$$
R: \phi \mapsto \phi(1)
$$
This map takes the identity to the identity. Is the kernel of this map something like the left isoclinic rotations or right isoclinic rotations? Is it even a group homomorphism? Is there any easy way to see this is not a homomorphism?  What nice properties does this map have?

The map $R$ is not a group homomorphism. Let
$$\phi = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\qquad \psi = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Note that $\phi, \psi \in SO(4)$ (they are $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rotations in the $ij$- and $1i$-planes respectively). Now $R(\phi\circ\psi) = (\phi\circ\psi)(1) = \phi(\psi(1)) = \phi(i) = j$, while $R(\phi)R(\psi) = \phi(1)\psi(1) = 1i = i \neq j$.

The kernel is just the set of rotations which preserve $1$. This is a copy of $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ but is neither of the isoclinic rotation groups as both of those contain $-I \in SO(4)$ which certainly doesn't preserve $1$. Instead this is the rotations in the hyperplane orthogonal to $1$ (i.e. $\operatorname{Im}(\mathbb{H})$).

I see, so the best way to think of this is as a group action of $ SO(4) $ on the manifold $ SU(2) $, where we are looking in particular at the orbit of $ 1\in SU(2) $ under the $ SO(4) $ action, then by orbit stabilizer theorem the stabilizer of this orbit is $ SO(3) $, all the rotations in the hyperplane orthogonal to $ 1 $ as you say. So we are obtaining the equation $ SO(4)/SO(3) \cong SU(2) $ which is well known since $ SU(2) $ is diffeomorphic to the $ 3 $-sphere.

I guess the question I'm still wondering is how do we tell if the map $ R $ is a group homomorphism? And if it is not how do we prove that?
